# How to remove the plain background color from an image

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to clear the plain background color from an image.

For example,

If i have a picture of a person standing in front of green background, i want the green color to be removed from the image.

Is there any code or API/SDK that performs this functionality.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

@John Rogers - I'm getting the below error when i try running your code. Am i doing anything wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];

const CGFloat colorMasking[6] = {minRed, maxRed, minGreen, maxGreen, minBlue, maxBlue};
image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(image.CGImage, colorMasking)];
```

Where min begins at 0 and max begins at 0. Each value is the number of components in the color space of the image.

Comment: I have a confusion on what value do i need to give on the place of {minRed, maxRed, minGreen, maxGreen, minBlue, maxBlue}

Comment: The documentation explains quite well: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImage/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors

Answer (score 0):

You should just use CGFloat instead of float.

```
const CGFloat colorMasking[6] = {minRed, maxRed, minGreen, maxGreen, minBlue, maxBlue};
```

Comment: Used to be fine with a float. Guess they changed it. Thanks for the heads up!